# Amazon Product Advertising API does not return rating and reviews

Tags: php, json, rest, amazon-product-api

I am exploring the Amazon Product advertisement API(PA 5). I am using the `GetItems` method. The API does not return ratings and reviews count. I have used amazon's scratchpad platform as well as PHP code for doing the same but no luck. I only got generic responses from Amazon's customer support as they say that one has to refer to online forums regarding this and they cannot provide a solution/explanation as to why the following data is not being returned.

Here is the JSON response I am getting with scratchpad.

```
{
 "ItemIds": [
  "B085WLFSJ1"
 ],
 "Resources": [
  "CustomerReviews.Count"
 ],
 "PartnerType": "Associates",
 "Marketplace": "www.amazon.com",
 "Operation": "GetItems"
}
```

Here is the PHP code I am using

```
<?php

$serviceName="ProductAdvertisingAPI";
$region="us-east-1";
$accessKey="myaccesskey";
$secretKey="mysecretkey";
$payload="{"
        ." \"ItemIds\": ["
        ."  \"B083JKTMYQ\""
        ." ],"
        ." \"Resources\": ["
        ."  \"CustomerReviews.Count\","
        ."  \"CustomerReviews.StarRating\","
        ."  \"Images.Primary.Small\","
        ."  \"Images.Primary.Medium\","
        ."  \"Images.Primary.Large\","
        ."  \"Images.Variants.Small\","
        ."  \"Images.Variants.Medium\","
        ."  \"Images.Variants.Large\""
        ." ],"
        ." \"PartnerTag\": \"sleephall08-20\","
        ." \"PartnerType\": \"Associates\","
        ." \"Marketplace\": \"www.amazon.com\""
        ."}";
$host="webservices.amazon.com";
$uriPath="/paapi5/getitems";
$awsv4 = new AwsV4 ($accessKey, $secretKey);
$awsv4->setRegionName($region);
$awsv4->setServiceName($serviceName);
$awsv4->setPath ($uriPath);
$awsv4->setPayload ($payload);
$awsv4->setRequestMethod ("POST");
$awsv4->addHeader ('content-encoding', 'amz-1.0');
$awsv4->addHeader ('content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
$awsv4->addHeader ('host', $host);
$awsv4->addHeader ('x-amz-target', 'com.amazon.paapi5.v1.ProductAdvertisingAPIv1.GetItems');
$headers = $awsv4->getHeaders ();
$headerString = "";
foreach ( $headers as $key => $value ) {
    $headerString .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\r\n";
}
$params = array (
        'http' => array (
            'header' => $headerString,
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $payload
        )
    );
$stream = stream_context_create ( $params );

$fp = @fopen ( 'https://'.$host.$uriPath, 'rb', false, $stream );

if (! $fp) {
    throw new Exception ( "Exception Occured" );
}
$response = @stream_get_contents ( $fp );
if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception ( "Exception Occured" );
}
echo $response;

class AwsV4 {

    private $accessKey = null;
    private $secretKey = null;
    private $path = null;
    private $regionName = null;
    private $serviceName = null;
    private $httpMethodName = null;
    private $queryParametes = array ();
    private $awsHeaders = array ();
    private $payload = "";

    private $HMACAlgorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256";
    private $aws4Request = "aws4_request";
    private $strSignedHeader = null;
    private $xAmzDate = null;
    private $currentDate = null;

    public function __construct($accessKey, $secretKey) {
        $this->accessKey = $accessKey;
        $this->secretKey = $secretKey;
        $this->xAmzDate = $this->getTimeStamp ();
        $this->currentDate = $this->getDate ();
    }

    function setPath($path) {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    function setServiceName($serviceName) {
        $this->serviceName = $serviceName;
    }

    function setRegionName($regionName) {
        $this->regionName = $regionName;
    }

    function setPayload($payload) {
        $this->payload = $payload;
    }

    function setRequestMethod($method) {
        $this->httpMethodName = $method;
    }

    function addHeader($headerName, $headerValue) {
        $this->awsHeaders [$headerName] = $headerValue;
    }

    private function prepareCanonicalRequest() {
        $canonicalURL = "";
        $canonicalURL .= $this->httpMethodName . "\n";
        $canonicalURL .= $this->path . "\n" . "\n";
        $signedHeaders = '';
        foreach ( $this->awsHeaders as $key => $value ) {
            $signedHeaders .= $key . ";";
            $canonicalURL .= $key . ":" . $value . "\n";
        }
        $canonicalURL .= "\n";
        $this->strSignedHeader = substr ( $signedHeaders, 0, - 1 );
        $canonicalURL .= $this->strSignedHeader . "\n";
        $canonicalURL .= $this->generateHex ( $this->payload );
        return $canonicalURL;
    }

    private function prepareStringToSign($canonicalURL) {
        $stringToSign = '';
        $stringToSign .= $this->HMACAlgorithm . "\n";
        $stringToSign .= $this->xAmzDate . "\n";
        $stringToSign .= $this->currentDate . "/" . $this->regionName . "/" . $this->serviceName . "/" . $this->aws4Request . "\n";
        $stringToSign .= $this->generateHex ( $canonicalURL );
        return $stringToSign;
    }

    private function calculateSignature($stringToSign) {
        $signatureKey = $this->getSignatureKey ( $this->secretKey, $this->currentDate, $this->regionName, $this->serviceName );
        $signature = hash_hmac ( "sha256", $stringToSign, $signatureKey, true );
        $strHexSignature = strtolower ( bin2hex ( $signature ) );
        return $strHexSignature;
    }

    public function getHeaders() {
        $this->awsHeaders ['x-amz-date'] = $this->xAmzDate;
        ksort ( $this->awsHeaders );

        // Step 1: CREATE A CANONICAL REQUEST
        $canonicalURL = $this->prepareCanonicalRequest ();

        // Step 2: CREATE THE STRING TO SIGN
        $stringToSign = $this->prepareStringToSign ( $canonicalURL );

        // Step 3: CALCULATE THE SIGNATURE
        $signature = $this->calculateSignature ( $stringToSign );

        // Step 4: CALCULATE AUTHORIZATION HEADER
        if ($signature) {
            $this->awsHeaders ['Authorization'] = $this->buildAuthorizationString ( $signature );
            return $this->awsHeaders;
        }
    }

    private function buildAuthorizationString($strSignature) {
        return $this->HMACAlgorithm . " " . "Credential=" . $this->accessKey . "/" . $this->getDate () . "/" . $this->regionName . "/" . $this->serviceName . "/" . $this->aws4Request . "," . "SignedHeaders=" . $this->strSignedHeader . "," . "Signature=" . $strSignature;
    }

    private function generateHex($data) {
        return strtolower ( bin2hex ( hash ( "sha256", $data, true ) ) );
    }

    private function getSignatureKey($key, $date, $regionName, $serviceName) {
        $kSecret = "AWS4" . $key;
        $kDate = hash_hmac ( "sha256", $date, $kSecret, true );
        $kRegion = hash_hmac ( "sha256", $regionName, $kDate, true );
        $kService = hash_hmac ( "sha256", $serviceName, $kRegion, true );
        $kSigning = hash_hmac ( "sha256", $this->aws4Request, $kService, true );

        return $kSigning;
    }

    private function getTimeStamp() {
        return gmdate ( "Ymd\THis\Z" );
    }

    private function getDate() {
        return gmdate ( "Ymd" );
    }
}
?>

<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://get.scrapehero.com/amz/product-reviews/?x-api-key=q9LJPUmr7e/TtEi/noQ0NeJ9kO/JGMEGctsDH/oK&asin=B07NFTVP7P&country_code=US&page=1&sort=top",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

Any help regarding this would be great.

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with this API but does https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/without-sdk.html#php have the same request format as what you're doing in PHP?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, using both the PHP and NodeJS SDKs. Perhaps this is an Amazon policy thing? Were you able to resonve this @lonedev?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Offers.Listings.MerchantInfo in your payload.

Then get the count and ratings from this return field. It only returns the last 30 days of feedback so it won't match the one listed on Amazon.

```
[MerchantInfo] => stdClass Object
(
[DefaultShippingCountry] => CN
[FeedbackCount] => 984
[FeedbackRating] => 4.89
[Id] => A1BKFNLPFGJ063
[Name] => Uineko
)
```